# Can the indivdual variables of a SystemVerilog struct be incremented with ++?

Tags: struct, system-verilog

I have defined a structure with three integers, then created a dynamic array of the structure. Later in the code, I want to increment some of the integer values in the structure:

```
typedef struct {
  integer tc;
  integer pass;
  integer fail;
} score_t; 

score_t    scorecard[]; 
integer    tc_count;

initial
....
scorecard = new[`MAX_TC]; 
....
scorecard[tc_count].fail  = 0;
....
scorecard[tc_count].fail++;
```

However, when I compile in Aldec Active-HDL I get the following error:

```
Error: VCP2615 ../../../m3_test_load_tb.sv : (283, 33): 
                    scorecard[tc_count].fail is not l-value.
```

Is this a limitation of the language? I can assign to a temporary variable to do the increment operation and then put the value back in the struct, but that seems clumsy.

Comment: The `++` syntax is legal in SystemVerilog. Make sure `tc_count` is not out of range,  must be less than `MAX_TC`. It could be causing the error.

Answer (score 4):

The code compiles with modelsim 10.1d. I have tested it on EDA Playground.

Seems the Aldec tool does not like the line:

```
scorecard[tc_count].fail++;
```

As a workaround you can replace the line with:

```
scorecard[tc_count].fail += 1;
```

Now it compiles with Aldec tool as well. http://www.edaplayground.com/x/VpV

Comment: Thanks @Coverify. I'd already taken the brute force approach and used    `scorecard[tc_count].fail = scorecard[tc_count].fail + 1;`   which works, but I was hoping to figure out if I was doing something illegal in SV or if it's just a bug with the tool. If I don't see anything more definitive, I'll pass this along to Aldec as a bug report

Comment: This is definitely legal. If `scorecard[tc_count].fail = scorecard[tc_count].fail + 1;` works, then `scorecard[tc_count].fail` must be an lvalue (an *lvalue* is an expression that is valid on the LHS of an assignment).