# SystemVerilog: How to create an interface which is an array of a simpler interfaces?

Tags: arrays, interface, system-verilog

I'm attempting to create an interface that is an array of a simpler interface. In VHDL I could simply define two types, a record and an array of records. But how to do this in SystemVerilog? Here's what I've tried:

```
`define MAX_TC 15

...

interface scorecard_if;
    score_if if_score [`MAX_TC];
endinterface

interface score_if;
    integer tc;
    integer pass;
    integer fail;
    bit     flag_match;
    real    bandwidth;
endinterface
```

But I get an error from Aldec Active-HDL:

Error: VCP2571 TestBench/m3_test_load_tb_interfaces.sv : (53, 34): 
Instantiations must have brackets (): if_score.

I also tried

```
interface scorecard_if;
    score_if  [`MAX_TC] if_score;
endinterface
```

and

```
interface scorecard_if;
    score_if [`MAX_TC];
endinterface
```

but both of those just resulted in "Unexpected token" syntax errors.

Is it even possible to do this? There are two workarounds that I can think of if there isn't a way to do this. First I could define all the individual elements of score_if as unpacked arrays:

```
interface score_if;
    integer tc         [1:`MAX_TC];
    integer pass       [1:`MAX_TC];
    integer fail       [1:`MAX_TC];
    bit     flag_match [1:`MAX_TC];
    real    bandwidth  [1:`MAX_TC];
endinterface
```

This compiles, but it's ugly in that I can no longer refer to a single score as a group.

I might also be to instantiate an array of score_if (using the original code), but I really want to instantiate scorecard_if inside a generate loop that would allow me instantiate a variable number of scorecard_if interfaces based on a parameter.

Just to provide a bit of explanation of what I'me trying to do, score_if is supposed to be a record of the score for a given test case, and scorecard_if an array for all of the test cases. But my testbench has multiple independent stimulus generators, monitors and scorecards to deal with multiple independent modules inside the DUT where the multiple is a parameter.

Comment: Try `` score_if if_score [`MAX_TC] (); ``

Comment: Thanks @Greg. That line compiles for me, but I've run into another issue when I try to reference the interface later in the code. This part works fine:               `score_if if_scorecard[`MAX_TC]();` but later on I try to reference the interface as follows:`         for (tc_idx = 1; tc_idx <= (tc_count-1); tc_idx++) begin  
            $display("  %3d       %3d     %3d     %g", if_scorecard[tc_idx].tc, if_scorecard[tc_idx].pass, if_scorecard[tc_idx].fail, if_scorecard[tc_idx].bandwidth);  
            total_failures = total_failures + if_scorecard[tc_idx].fail;  
        end //for`

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, but while the formatting in the original question was really easy, I can't seem to get it to work properly in the comments and the five minute limit on editing comments doesn't allow for a lot of second chances. :(

Comment: Inserting two spaces  or <br/> doesn't seem to insert a carriage return.

Comment: The error I get from Aldec Active-HDL regarding the reference to the if array is as follows: Instance/Gate selection with variable index is forbidden: tc_idx

Comment: Berry, You should edit you question to include your second part of your question instead of posting it as comments. Especially when it contains significant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Part 1 : Declaring an array of interfaces

Add parentheses to the end of the interface instantiation. According to [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html), all instantiations of hierarchical instances need the parentheses for the port list even if the port list is blank. Some tools allow dropping the parentheses if the interfaces doesn't have any ports in the declaration and and the instantiation is simple; but this is not part of the standard. Best practice is to use parentheses for all hierarchical instantiation.

Solution:

```
score_if if_score [`MAX_TC] () ;
```

Syntax Citations:

- § 25.3 *Interface syntax* & § A.4.1.2 *Interface instantiation*

  > interface_instantiation ::=           // from A.4.1.2
  >   interface_identifier [ parameter_value_assignment ] hierarchical_instance { **,** hierarchical_instance } **;**
- § A.4.1.1 *Module instantiation*

  > hierarchical_instance ::= name_of_instance **(** [ list_of_port_connections ] **)**

---

## Part 2: Accessing elements for that array

Hierarchical references must be constant. Arrayed hierarchical instances cannot be accessed by dynamic indexes.  It is an rule/limitation since at least IEEE Std 1364. Read more about it in [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 23.6 *Hierarchical names*, and the syntax rule is:

> hierarchical_identifier ::= [ **$root .** ] { identifier constant_bit_select **.** } identifier

You could use a generate-for-loop, as it does an static unroll at compile/elaboration time. The limitation is you cannot use your display message our accumulate your fail count in the loop. You could use the generate loop to copy data to a local array and sum that, but that defeated your intention.

An interface is normally a bundle of nets used to connect modules with class-base test-bench or shared bus protocols. You are using it as a nested score card. A `typedef struct` would likely be better suited to your purpose. A `struct` is a data type and does not have the hierarchical reference limitation as modules and interfaces. It looked like you were already trying rout in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27629778/1959732). Not sure why you switched to nesting interfaces.

It looks like you are trying to create a fairly complex test environment. If so, I suggest learning [UVM](http://www.accellera.org/downloads/standards/uvm) before spending to much time reinventing for a advance testbench architecture. Start with 1.1d as 1.2 isn't mainstream yet.

Comment: Thanks again @Greg. This explains my issues. Unfortunately, I can't use UVM at this time for a couple of reasons: 1. Our tools don't support the full SV implementation, only what Aldec calls the SV "design" subset. 2 Management  isn't going to want to support the learning curve and licence costs to move to UVM right now. This was supposed to be a VHDL only project, we got forced into using Verilog for the testbench because we are using the Xilinx Zynq BFMs that only work with Verilog.

Comment: I would happily use a struct but it appears that I can't use structs as a port--but if there is someway to that it would make life much easier for me.

Comment: Sounds like outdated/bad tools. Make sure you have the latest version of Active-HDL (10.1). Structs are part of SV "Design"; according to my coworker's copy of [SystemVerilog for Desing](http://www.amazon.com/SystemVerilog-Design-Second-Edition-Hardware/dp/1441941258), & tested w/ my tools. For your current project, have management bring in an AE form Aldec (included in the licensing agreements?). UVM is free to use and you can self-learn for free on your own time. All the material is available online including online simulators (ex [edaplaygorund](http://www.edaplayground.com/)).

Comment: Aldec structures the Active-HDL license such that SV Design is included in the basic license but SV Assertions and SV Verification are add-on licenses (we just priced this out a couple of weeks ago). I do want to learn UVM (I took an introductory 1/2 day class at DAC last year) but there simply isn't time to ramp on it for this project. We didn't even plan for the initial ramp on SV design. :)

Comment: Sorry I misread your comment. You are correct about structs and it looks like that is the way to go here instead of an interface. I must have misread the description of structs somewhere and mistakenly thought they were not supported as ports.

Answer (score 1):

This also works:
1. define a "container" interface:

```
interface environment_if (input serial_clk);
    serial_if               eng_if[`NUM_OF_ENGINES](serial_clk);
    virtual serial_if       eng_virtual_if[`NUM_OF_ENGINES];
endinterface
```

2. in the testbench instantiate env_if connect serial_if with generate, connect the virtual if with the non virtual and pass the virtual if to the verification env:

```
module testbench;
   ....
   environment_if   env_if(serial_clk);
   .....
   dut   i_dut(...);
   genvar eng_idx
   generate
   for(eng_idx=0; eng_idx<`NUM_OF_ENGINES; eng_idx++) begin
       env_if.eng_if[eng_idx].serial_bit = assign i_dut.engine[eng_idx].serial_bit;
   end
   endgenerate
   ......

   initial begin
      env_if.eng_virtual_if = env_if.eng_if[0:`NUM_OF_ENGINES-1]; 
      //now possible to iterate over eng_virtual_if[]
      for(int eng_idx=0; eng_idx<`NUM_OF_ENGINES; eng_idx++)
          uvm_config_db#(virtual serial_if)::set(null, "uvm_test_top.env", "tx_vif", env_if.env_virtual_if[eng_idx]);
   end
endmodule
```

Comment: It tells me`Syntax error near assign`